# FFmpeg decode raw buffer with avcodec_decode_video2

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am receiving a h264 stream where I at least know the size of one frame. The stream is coming in right as I can store it in a file and playback with vlc. Playing back a file is no problem for me as I include the libavformat. But libavformat gives me back an AVPacket which I can directly give to avcodec_decode_video2. In this case I got a bytestream. How can I give the raw h264 stream to the avcodec_decode_video2? How can I wrap my data into a AVPacket. VLC does not need to guess any data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more or less easy to decode a stream. This code is working perfect for me:

```
class ffmpegstreamdestination
{
public:
    ffmpegstreamdestination(AVCodecID decoder): 
    {       
        m_pCodec= avcodec_find_decoder(decoder);
        m_pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_pCodec);
        avcodec_open2(m_pCodecCtx,m_pCodec,0);
        m_pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();
    }

    ~ffmpegstreamdestination()
    {
        av_free(m_pFrame);
        avcodec_close(m_pCodecCtx);
    }

    void decodeStreamData(unsigned char * pData, size_t sz)
    {
        AVPacket        packet;
        av_init_packet(&packet);

        packet.data=pData;
        packet.size=(int)sz;
        int framefinished=0;
        int nres=avcodec_decode_video2(m_pCodecCtx,m_pFrame,&framefinished,&packet);

        if(framefinished)
        {
                   // do the yuv magic and call a consumer
        }

        return;
    }

protected:
    AVCodecContext  *m_pCodecCtx;
    AVCodec         *m_pCodec;
    AVFrame         *m_pFrame;
};
```

the call decodeStreamData expect the data as frames. You have to search your stream for the NAL (more or less a header magic number) which is in h264 case 0x00000001 .Its the beginning of a frame. Filling the AVPacket is not as problematic as I thought. If you do not have the information, you can left the attributes in it as the are init by av_init_packet. There are only problems if you have a different framerate for example.

As always, if you see a bug or think something would work otherwise better, a short message would be welcome.

Comment: hi, how can i parse `0x00000001`, because this start codes repeats before `SPS` and `PPS`?

Comment: @nmxprime it is better to start a new question about that. As far as I know, you can simply iterate through pData like: for(size_t i=0;i<sz-4;i++) if((pData[i]==0x00)&&(pData[i+1]==0x00)&&(pData[i+2]==0x00)&&(pData[i+3]==0x01)) {/* i is the start here */} but be carefull, you need special buffer boundary check code

Comment: i tried like this, but i may be iterating wrongly, so not succeeded ! Let me try!!Actually, Typically the file contains data for 100 frames,which means 100's of`(sps,pps and data)`. The same start code is used for sps,pps and data. BTW, what boundary checking you're telling of?

Comment: @nmxprime our question is going to far to response it in the comment section. Open a new question with your code. Add a comment here to your question and I + 1 million coders will look into your problem :-)

Comment: I have raw data from RTSP stream. Getting this error "[h264 @ 001436e0] no frame!", "nres" value is always less than 0. Any hing whats wrong with my code?

Comment: @Tariq Post a new question with an example code. Your problem may be the streamdata itself, not the decoding.

Comment: avcodec_decode_video2 is deprecated, use avcodec_send_packet instead.
Source: Documentation in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/avcodec.h