# Decode compressed frame to memory using LibAV: avcodec_decode_video2?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, decode, libav

I am completely new to libAV.

I have a single video frame coming from somewhere else (it's in memory, not in a file). It should be H.264 encoded keyframe.

I'm trying to decode with `avcodec_decode_video2` is that the right function for my needs?

I'm encountering a problem using this code (basically taken from [FFmpeg decode raw buffer with avcodec_decode_video2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786781/ffmpeg-decode-raw-buffer-with-avcodec-decode-video2) ):

```
AVCodecContext  *m_pCodecCtx;
AVCodec         *m_pCodec;
AVFrame         *m_pFrame;

m_pCodec= avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_H264);
m_pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_pCodec);
avcodec_open2(m_pCodecCtx,m_pCodec,0);

// since avcodec_alloc_frame() isn't existing anymore, I changed to following:
//m_pFrame=m_fc.avcodec_alloc_frame(); // and what is/was m_fc?!?
m_pFrame = av_frame_alloc();


AVPacket        packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);

packet.data = (unsigned char*)mData;
packet.size=(int)mDataSize;

// this is for decoding a keyframe?
packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

int framefinished=0;
int nres=avcodec_decode_video2(m_pCodecCtx,m_pFrame,&framefinished,&packet);

if(framefinished)
{
    std::cout << "decoded frame" << std::endl
}
```

unfortunately `framefinished` always returns 0 while `nres` is 18331 which equals `mDataSize`

Where's my fault? 
Do I have to specify codec information more clearly? 
Is my packet broken or incomplete?
Am I using the wrong libAV function?

In the sample code of the framework I'm using, the image data is succesfully streamed to a file, using `av_interleaved_write_frame` (and a `AvFormatContext`). Can this help me configuring my packet or the codec?

Comment: What is the value of nres when avcodec_decode_video2 returns?

Comment: @biskitt `nres = 18331` which equals `mDataSize`. `avcodec_open2` returns 0. Do I have to specify my image resolution somewhere? Codec Options? In most examples they use `av_read_frame` to fill the packet, but that's not applicable here, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `nres` being positive, and equal to `mDataSize` means that everything is ok, your decoding is done with this packet. `framefinished == 0` only means that the frame was not written.

It may be because your frame data is shared between several packets, so you need to call `avcodec_decode_video2`with the following packets, until you have a full frame.

Another possible explanation: your codec have a delay between input and output: it gives you nothing on the first call, and need a last call with an empty packet to get the last frame. What you need to do is call something like

```
AVPacket emptyPacket;
av_init_packet(&emptyPacket);
emptyPacket.data = NULL;
emptyPacket.size = 0;
emptyPacket.stream_index = packet.stream_index;
nres=avcodec_decode_video2(m_pCodecCtx,m_pFrame,&framefinished,&emptyPacket);
```

See the note on `CODEC_CAP_DELAY` [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga99ee61b6dcffb7817a275d39da58cc74)

Comment: thx alot. I get a frame on calling with empty package after the previous call. What kind of format does this frame have? I assumed YUV 24 Bit per Pixel, but there are only vertical lines on the image. I'll try to collect more packets first now.

Comment: Your format is in `m_pFrame->format`. Possible values are there https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html#a9a8e335cf3be472042bc9f0cf80cd4c5. It often is YUV420P, which is a planar format (one full size buffer for Y, two smaller buffers for U and V).

Comment: I am facing same issue but decoding again with empty packet is not solving my problem. But if I give it next packet after reading data from stream, then it decodes 0 bytes but gives framefinished as 1.