# OpenCV - how to read video from buffer?

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer

Reading video from disk is simple - `CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);`, but I need to read `mp4` file which is already in `std::string VideoBuffer`.

**How to do that?**

Comment: use ffmpeg library directly

Comment: ??? Could you explain please?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786781/ffmpeg-decode-raw-buffer-with-avcodec-decode-video2